# Ngrx @Effects - Make it stop immediately

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store-4.0

I have the following ngrx effect. Inside "map" I have a condition. How can I stop the effect immediately without continue to the mergeMap.

```js
@Effect()
myEffect$: Observable < Action > = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType('INIT_ACADEMY_DOMAIN'),
  map((action: any) => {
    const url = 'http://www.academy.xyzq';
    if (1 === 1) {
      // Make this effect stop immediately and do nothing more
    }
    action.url = url;
    return action;
  }),
  mergeMap((action: any) =>
    this.http.get(action.url).pipe(
      switchMap((data: any) => {
        return [{
          type: 'INIT_ACADEMY',
          payload: {
            academy: data.academy
          }
        }];
      })
    )),
  catchError(() => of ({
    type: 'INIT_IT_FAILED'
  }))
);
```

Comment: I would suggest to use the takeUntil operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can try like this.

@Effect()
myEffect$: Observable < Action > = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType('INIT_ACADEMY_DOMAIN'),
  map((action: any) => {
    const url = 'http://www.academy.xyzq';
    if (1 === 1) {
      // Make this effect stop immediately and do nothing more
      return null;
    }
    action.url = url;
    return action;
  }),
  mergeMap((action: any) =>
    if(action){
    return this.http.get(action.url).pipe(
      switchMap((data: any) => {
        return [{
          type: 'INIT_ACADEMY',
          payload: {
            academy: data.academy
          }
        }];
      })
      } else{
        return null;
      }
    )),
  catchError(() => of ({
    type: 'INIT_IT_FAILED'
  }))
);
```

Comment: I try this... but i had a strange issue... As soon as the condition is false and didn't pass from return null everything works perfect. By the time the condition became true... everytime i dispatch a new action to this effect... doesn't work anymore.... Strange...

Comment: return statement is missing for second mergeMap. updated.

Comment: You have some syntax errors... but yes... this is the solution

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using the `filter` function to filter out actions based on your condition:

```
@Effect()
myEffect$: Observable < Action > = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType('INIT_ACADEMY_DOMAIN'),
  filter((x) => 1 === 1),
  mergeMap((action: any) =>
    this.http.get(action.url).pipe(
      switchMap((data: any) => {
        return [{
          type: 'INIT_ACADEMY',
          payload: {
            academy: data.academy
          }
        }];
      })
    )),
  catchError(() => of ({
    type: 'INIT_IT_FAILED'
  }))
);
```

Alternatively you could just dispatch a new action if your condition is true and create a simpler effect that executes the part inside your `mergeMap` function.

You should try to keep your effects as simple as possible. If your effect does a lot of logic / condition checks, it is hard to find a suitable name that captures what the effect really does.